# Ordered high performance key-value DBMS

Tags: gratis, library, java, database, key-value-store

I need an ordered key-value database (pretty much like LevelDB) for Java. Additionally to the set of features provided by Level DB, I also need the following :

- Being able to get a keys position in the database.
- Being able to supply a custom comparator.

Is there any (free, ideally open source) software which matches my needs ?

Answer (score 1):

For my purpose, Redis' sorted sets seem to be fitting (suggestion by someone on Discord) : https://redis.io/topics/data-types

I used Jedis as client.

Comment: This is bit confusing to me. LevelDB is an embedded DB, while Redis isn't. If embedded  isn't a requirement, LevelDB is a non-starter. If it is, then Redis is a non-starter.

Comment: I would've preferred embedded, but LevelDB didn't have the required functionality.